# Getting textbox value from X-editable

Tags: ajax, django, x-editable

How do you get the value of the textbox field and send as `data` inside of `ajaxOptions`? I tested my view and it prints out the test variable successfully from my Django views. I am using `X-editable` for Jquery. Heres what textbox input looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/197/

**views.py**

```
def create_post(request):

    print request.POST.get("test", "");
    return HttpResponse(json,content_type="application/json")
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="other1" data-pk="First Name" data-name="test">First Name</a>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#other1').editable({
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            url: '/create_post/', 
            ajaxOptions: {

                    data: {

                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    test: "hi",
                    },


                },  
            placement: 'top',
            title: 'New Expense',
            success: function(response, newValue) {
                if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg; //ms
            },  

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ajaxOptions`, use `params`. If I remember correctly, `test` and its value will be included in your POST request by x-editable. Try something like this:

**Html**

```
<a id="other1" data-pk="1" data-name="test">First Name</a>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#other1').editable({
        type: 'text',
        url: '/create_post/', 
        params : function(params) {
            params.csrfmiddlewaretoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
            return params;
        }, 
        placement: 'top',
        title: 'New Expense',
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg; //ms
        },  

    });
});
```